# in react-router, how to invoke a link directly from code api?

Tags: react-router

e.g.:

```
this.onClick = function(){
  // current path is '#/list'
  // i want to go to '#/detail' by invoke an api

  //how could i do?
}
```

So far i have not found any available api in react-router.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `History` module, which you probably already use with the React Router. Then you could do:

```js
this.props.history.push('/yourPath');
```

You can read more in the [Navigating Outside Components](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md) docs. Also see the [Navigating section in CHANGES](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/CHANGES.md#navigating).